# how can I make an arrow point upwards at the bottom of my header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website. I have a header which has several tabs at bottom of which I want to add an arrow (looks like a small triangle) if I am current on the page corresponding to that tab.

|  tab1  |  tab2  |  tab3  |

---^------------------------

<--Tab1 Content here -->

I don't want to use img to solve. Is there any way to do it by using css or javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

No need for javascript, it's pure CSS.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

More examples and articles [here](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+trianble#hl=en&newwindow=1&sa=X&ei=CcIWT_CzHIuk-gaXn9WxBA&ved=0CBcQvwUoAQ&q=css+triangle&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=34a431a839d504d0&biw=1349&bih=779).

Comment: @pduersteler: maybe next time :-)

Answer (score 3):

i thank you can use special symbol like "▲" and give it some css rules to make it match your needs.
And you can also use pure css rules and a html element to solve it. please look my demo at http://wandouyouxi.com/cnblogs/css/untitled-1.html

Comment: i think this is the easiest method

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility are HTML symbol entities:

```
Filled triangle pointing down          &#9660;  
Filled vertical triangle               &#9650;
```

Result: ▼ ▲

Then you could use CSS to (absolute) position the symbol (relative) to the header item.

Taken from http://llizard.etherwork.net/cwc/charactmap.html